# How to properly compile a python program to a binary

Tags: python, cython

I'm compiling a python program using cython like this:

```
cython --embed myprg.py && gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o myprg myprg.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

If I run *myprg* I geht the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'ModuleImporterFromVariables' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myprg.py", line 9, in init myprg (myprg.c:2219)
    import json
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 892, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 873, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 3256, in find_module
    while in_importlib(parent_frame):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 3204, in in_importlib
    return frame.f_code.co_filename == "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_code'
```

My python program is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sh
import os
import traceback
import shutil
import sys
import json

print(sys.argv[1:])
```

It seems that the compiled program is not capable of loading the *json* module while the other modules work well. Some tests showed this seems to be the case with the *argparse* module as well.

My question: Why is this the case and how can I work around/fix that?

--

Additional notes:

As far as I understand this after compiling with cython the binary will make use of some kind of method of "sh.py" - part of the "sh" package. In this package for some reason a method checks for imports using the following code:

```
""" helper for checking if a filename is in importlib guts """
return frame.f_code.co_filename == "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"
```

As there does not seem to be a stack frame available running the program based on the cython output, this method fails with an exception.

As far as I know this error did not occur some time ago. It is new. It seems that something changed in python in the last months that breaks the cython way of building a binary. Has anyone more information about this?

Comment: Perhaps you can file a bug report (if that is what it is).

Comment: I am not sure if it is a bug. I seems somehow, but I'm not sure about it. Maybe I'm just missing something? I'd like to hear what people with more experience with cython think about this. There certainly are people out there that compile python to binaries? And regarding "file a bug report". To whom and where? Is this a python or a cython bug? Cython should have some bug tracking. Unfortunately their bug tracking system does not work. I hope I'm wrong but that gives me the impression the project somehow is abandoned.